# Last item is skipped by custom sorting/removing of duplicates in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a code in c to remove duplicates in singly linked list. I am doing it by first inserting numbers through dynamic allocation and then sorting the list and then finally removing the duplicates.

The code is working for all cases except if the last number is itself duplicate then the last number is not sorted and hence it is not removed.

The following is my code and below the output it is showing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
struct data{
     int a;
     struct data *rear;
};

int main()
{
  struct data *cur,*prev,*first,*next,*temp,*nxt;
  int t;
  char ch='y';
  cur=(struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
  cur->rear=NULL;
  first=cur;
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&cur->a);
  printf("Do you wish to enter any other number? y/n \n");
  setbuf(stdin,NULL);
  while((ch=getchar())!='n')
     {
        prev=cur;
        cur=(struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        printf("Enter the no.: \n");
        scanf("%d",&cur->a);
        prev->rear=cur;
        cur->rear=NULL;
        printf("Wish to continue still? y/n \n");
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);

     }
  cur=first;
  printf("Printing values from begining to end of the list:\n");
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",cur->a);
        sleep(1);
        cur=cur->rear;
    }
    cur=first;
  printf("Looking for duplicate numbers and removing them\n");
  sleep(2);
  printf("Now showing \n Sorted list with duplicates removed:\n");
  for(;cur->rear!=NULL;cur=cur->rear)
  {
    for(nxt=cur->rear;nxt!=NULL;nxt=nxt->rear)
    {
        if(cur->a>nxt->a)
        {
            t=cur->a;
            cur->a=nxt->a;
            nxt->a=t;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
 }

 cur=first;
 for(;cur->rear!=NULL;cur=cur->rear)
  {
     for(next=cur->rear;next->rear!=NULL;next=next->rear)
     {
        if(cur->a==next->a)
        {
            temp=next->rear;
            free(cur->rear);
            cur->rear=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
     }
  }

cur=first;
while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",cur->a);
        cur=cur->rear;
    }

return 0;
}
```

output :

```
Enter a number                                                                                                                                             
23                                                                                                                                                         
Do you wish to enter any other number? y/n                                                                                                                 
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
12                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
23                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
12                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
33                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
78                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
9                                                                                                                                                          
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
y                                                                                                                                                          
Enter the no.:                                                                                                                                             
78                                                                                                                                                         
Wish to continue still? y/n                                                                                                                                
n                                                                                                                                                          
Printing values from begining to end of the list:                                                                                                          
23                                                                                                                                                         
12                                                                                                                                                         
23                                                                                                                                                         
12                                                                                                                                                         
33                                                                                                                                                         
78                                                                                                                                                         
9                                                                                                                                                          
78                                                                                                                                                         
Looking for duplicate numbers and removing them                                                                                                            
Now showing                                                                                                                                                
 Sorted list with duplicates removed:                                                                                                                      
9       12      23      33      78      78                                                                                                                 

...Program finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Functions have been invented there for a reason :D

Comment: @moooeeeep it is giving same output

Comment: @moooeeeep yeah its working. i gave cur!=NULL instead of cur->rear!=NULL. Same for next and nxt also. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
cur->rear!=NULL
```

to this:

```
cur!=NULL
```

and do the same for `next` and `nxt`.

PS: You should really learn about using functions. For example, check this [listmanagement.c](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/), and get an idea of how functions can be used when building a list.

Comment: You are telling the opposite. I changed cur->rear!=NULL  to cur!=NULL and same for next and nxt and now its working. But yeah I will keep the function part in mind next time. Thanks.

Comment: Oops sorry @kaushikchatterjee, answer updated. Since this solves the issue, consider *accepting* the answer.